# How to install w32codecs on 64 Bit Ubuntu?

Tags: video

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMD64 it is possible.
However a detailed step by step on how to install w32codecs on a 64 Bit Ubuntu is not given.

Answer (score 1):

**From the MPlayer's mouth**

The MPlayer download /1/ page is telling:

```
Instructions for installing binary codecs can be found in the README...
```

and the README /2/ is telling:

```
STEP1: Installing Binary Codecs
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Unpack the codecs archives and put the contents in a directory where MPlayer
will find them...
```

**From the Medibuntu**

The Ubuntu Community Documentation of Medibuntu /3/ is telling the basic information of the Medibuntu /4/. From the Medibuntu you could download either the tar packed w32codecs (source package) or the Debian packed codecs.

**Acrchive is an archive**

Both the .tar and the . deb are archives. You could unpack both. The Debian package archive (.deb) can also hold instructions for the package management system.

w32codecs_20110131.orig.tar.gz has:

- codecs to installed where ever you want them.

w32codecs_20110131-0.1medibuntu3_i386.deb has:

- a preinst script, will remove the /usr/lib/win32/ directory if there are one
- codecs to installed to the /usr/lib/codecs/
- symlinks /5/ to made from /usr/lib/codecs/ to /usr/lib/win32/

**Links**

1. http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html
2. http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/README
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu
4. http://www.medibuntu.org/
5. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link